# Does over training exist?

Tags: recovery, overtraining

Is it true that overtraining does not exist but its instead just under-recovery as to not rest,sleep,drink and eat enough?

Comment: I wouldn't know, so I'm interested in the answers that will come forward, but I can't imagine there is no limit to the amount of training a human body can withstand/handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's be specific: by "overtraining", we really mean "applying a stress from which the organism cannot recover and adapt" in the context of [the General Adaptation Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(biology)#General_adaptation_syndrome), which we can summarize here as "stress, recovery, and adaptation".

So, the question becomes: "Is it possible to stress oneself (that is, volitionally) to an unrecoverable extent?"  I'm unsure whether this is possible.  The accounts of [Pheidippides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pheidippides) suggest that **yes, it is possible**.  I suspect that other examples exist.

On the other hand, the vast majority of us [probably aren't "overtrained".](http://www.jtsstrength.com/articles/2012/12/20/you-are-not-overtrained/)

Comment: Rhabdomyolysis - A condition of overwork that leads to actual tissue death, which can then cause kidney damage/failure and actual real death if not treated. Was a problem in the early days if HIIT/Crossfit type gyms, often referred to as "Uncle Rhabdo".

Comment: It seems like distinguishing _over-reaching_, and _over-training_ is a good idea.  Since one can be done easily, and the other is much more serious but way less common.